# How can I align nodes along the same vertical line without adding invisible edges?

Tags: graphviz

I have the following digraph:

```
digraph G
{
   rankdir=TB


   l1 -> l2 -> l3 -> l4 -> l5 -> l6 -> l7;

    f1a -> s1
    f1b -> s1
    f1c -> s1
    f1d -> s1
    s1 -> fo1a
    s1 -> fo1b
    s1 -> fo1c

   f2b -> s2
   s2 -> fo2a
   s2 -> fo2b

   fo1a -> s2

   fo2a -> s3 [style=invis]
   fo2b -> s3 [style=invis]


  {rank=same; l1; f1a; f1b; f1c; f1d}
  {rank=same; l3; fo1a; fo1b; fo1c;}
  {rank=same; l4; f2b;}

   s1 [shape=box]
   s2 [shape=box]
   s3 [shape=box]
}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

Is there a way to vertically align boxes s1, s2 and s3 without adding invisible edges?

Adding invisible edges works, but I'm working in a tool for generating flowcharts and calculating those edges implies a more complex algorithm... so I'm searching for an alternative.

Adding this code I'll get the desired result:

```
   fo1a -> s2 
   fo1b -> f2b [style=invis]
```

I've created a [jsfiddle with the graph](http://jsfiddle.net/bitfhacker/ds93unq3/light/).

Comment: can you share What have you tried so far??

Comment: 'Considering the following...' doesn't scream 'homework!' at all.

Comment: I see your point. I'll edit my question.

Comment: If the generation of those flowchart graphs is that complex that you can't extract the nodes which need to be aligned and add (invisble) edges between them, how could any other solution (except placing each node manually) even know which nodes to align?